# When should be correct to versioning using pull requests

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, travis-ci, versioning, release-management

I've been working in a project in GitHub, I was wondering, when should I release versions using pull requests, I want know a good practice.

Context: Master is the default branch, protected and only accept PR reviewed and passing Travis CI checks.

I want to create a branch named "feature/hello-world", modify my branch and push to repo, then create a pull request to master, pass all checks, then when the reviewer merge to master, Travis CI create a new tag, npm version patch to update `package.json`, deploy new version to Heroku and update master's branch files.

This is the repo's link: https://github.com/gpincheiraa/bln-frontend-project1

Comment: I suggest you have another branch between master and feature branches, where you can test several features together before deciding to merge it to master, and on every merge to master it will be a new version